# unix:////tmp/supervisor.sock refused connection

Tags: connection, connection-refused

Blessings guys... first, sorry for my bad English, my first language is Spanish.

So, I have a website for translations. We translate from English to Spanish (tv shows), the thing is that we have a real time translation system installed by a friend.

So, he explained to me (last year when he installed it) that if the real time server goes down, that the system automatically will reset the real time server but in case that it won't reset, that I have to use the command: supervisorctl restart tusubtrt

So, when I use that command I get: unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock refused connection

And I cant do anything more because I dont know anything of Networking :$

I tried to communicate with him, but I dont have connection with him right now.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like supervisord isn't running. Not sure which distro you are running but try these commands to see if it'll start

```
service supervisor start
```

or

```
service supervisord start
```

or

```
systemctl start supervisor
```

or

```
systemctl start supervisord
```

on any of those commands you can replace `start` with `status` to see the status of the service and if that might have been the right command